# Why dielectric waveguides support hybrid modes and metallic waveguides don't?

Tags: dielectric, metals, fiber-optics, waveguide, normal-modes

Can anyone explain me **qualitatively**, why dielectric waveguides (core and infinite cladding) support hybrid modes ($E_z$ and $H_z$ components in the guided wave) while metallic waveguides cannot. I am sure it is about the boundary conditions but I need a more deep explanation, not necessarily with equations.

Comment: If you fill a metallic waveguide *partially* or just with transversally inhomogeneous dielectric you get hybrid modes. That a homogeneously filled metallic guide can support pure TM or TE modes is an accident of nature, so to speak, hybrid modes are the normal normal... In my view a qualitative explanation is more needed to explain why a homogeneous waveguide supports TE/TM modes but I do not have any.

Comment: and to make matters more interesting the cutoff modes are pure TM/TE even when the propagating ones are hybrid!